# Errors occur when trying including SerialStram.h from LibSerial

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, libserial

I try to use LibSerial’s class for serial communication (with an ATMega32A) through a COM port.
As soon as I include the SerialStream.h I get several error messages from the file SerialPort.h.

```
#include "SerialStream.h"
```

You can see the errors I get here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8ZdC.png

Since I did not fully understand the installation of LibSerial, I think I use the class the wrong way.
I use the compiler QT Creator and the OS is Windows 7.
Feel free to ask for more information if you need it.

Comment: As you are using Qt do you really need libserial ? maybe it's easier if you use QSerialPort ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not answerable in it's current format.

Nevertheless, if you are willing to use Qt's features to read from a serial port, I could point you to [a demo I wrote a while ago](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/QtSerial).

Quick notes: **main.cpp** retrieves information and detects all serial ports on the computer and presents a menu to let the user choose which port to read from. Then it uses `QSerialPort` to open a connection to that specific port, and the reading part is done by [`SerialPortReader`](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/blob/master/QtSerial/serialportreader.cpp), a class implemented on that project.

Comment: Thank you. That seems usable but I need to both read and write.

Comment: Just invoke `QSerialPort::write()` for that.